# Fixed Point of a Gaussian

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any analytic method to compute $x$ such that $e^{-x^{2}} = x$? Came across this in some game theory I am doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewrite it as $xe^{x^2}=1$. Square and then double both sides (in that order) to obtain

$$2x^2e^{2x^2}=2.$$

Now apply the [Lambert-W](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function to both sides and get $2x^2=W(2)$, hence

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{W(2)}{2}}\approx 0.652919.$$